# How to find out if an Google Play app is for phone or tablet?

Tags: android, google-play, aapt

I have a task where I have to find if the application supports for phone or a tablet, that is available on the Google Play Store. I have two ways of accessing the app information:

1. Using selenium automation to search an app url and get the  app information.
2. pull the apk file and do aapt dump badging <.apk location>

   The aapt dumping gives me values of support screens as below:

   ```
    supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
   ```

   Is this enough to tell if an app is meant for phones or tablets or both?

Comment: It's a pretty vague semantic distinction. I think `supports-screens` is about as concrete as you're going to get.

Comment: I wouldn't count on those values. Most apps don't specify these values and the assumed default varies. I believe Google filters based on the presence or absence of tablet-sized screenshots.

Comment: @Krylez While it's true that many apps just use the default, it is absolutely **not** true that Google filters based on screenshots.

Comment: When I say "filter" I mean you won't see apps in tablet-specific categories if there are no tablet screenshots. They're still available, just not promoted in those particular categories.